# variable initialization with int()

Tags: c++, variable-initialization

I was trying some different ways of initializing variables.

```
int a(0);
cout<<a;
```

for this code segment output is `0` .

in another way, I initialize `a` with `0`

```
int a= int();
cout<<a;

output: 0
```

then I try this:

```
int a(int());
  cout<<a;
```

this time output is `1`

actually what does the value the int() function return ?  `0` or `1`

Comment: Ah, most vexing parse, we meet again.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse Basically, the `int a(int());` is treated as a function declaration

Comment: @JoachimPileborg , in that question , there is no use of int() function , i want to know what int() is doing here ?

Answer (score 2):

I think that your last attempt (`int a(int())`) is an example of the "most vexing parse". Thus, `a` is a function, not an int.

This:

```
#include <typeinfo>

std::cout << typeid(a).name() << std::endl;
```

Yields:

```
FiPFivEE
```

And putting this result [here](http://pear.warosu.org/c++filtjs/) gives:

```
int ()(int (*)())
```

Comment: while i am writing int a(0) . 

Is a is an int or a function here ???

Comment: @lukai You should read this article (http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/09/gotw-1-solution/) that explains the possible syntaxes for initializing a variable

Comment: @piwi I don't know.  First, it only applies to C++11, which most professionals can't use yet.  And second, it contains a fair amount of bad advice (like preferring the obfuscating and error prone `auto` forms over the more explicit forms).

Comment: @JamesKanze it does not applies to C++11 *only*

Comment: @piwi The article you site is full of syntax which is only valid in C++11.  Standardizing on the new initialization sequence _is_ a good idea, but it will take a few years before people in industry can do so.  Using `auto` everywhere (another recommendation in the article) is a horrible idea, however; it obfuscates, and is very error prone.

Comment: @JamesKanze Regarding `auto`, what do you mean by error-prone? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @piwi With `auto`, you don't necessarily know the actual type, and it can change as a result of changes elsewhere.  So you start out safe, with a signed integral type, and a change in basically unrelated code suddenly turns it into a problematic unsigned type.

Answer (score 0):

Doing `int()` creates a temporary integer and value initialize it.Value initialized integers without a specific value will have the value zero. So the declaration

```
int a = int();
```

value initializes a temporary integer, and copies it to `a`.

However for the third example, as many have pointed out, you actually declare a function named `a`.

Comment: that means int a(int ()) , in this case int() didn't play any role here.

Comment: "Doing int() creates a temporary integer and default constructs it. Default constructed integers will have the value zero.": The correct sentences are, actually, "Doing int() creates a temporary integer and value initialize it. Value initialized integers will have the value zero.".

Comment: He declares a function returning `int` and taking a pointer to a function as an argument.  He doesn't "create" it, and if he tries to use the function, he would still need a definition elsewhere.